# DotNet Core Kestrel sends response header in lower case

Tags: .net-core, openshift, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

We have containerized our DotNetCore app using Docker and running on OpenShift.

We are add few custom response headers and we observed that the custom response headers are returned in Lower case though we specify like "Header-Name" it returns as "header-name"

Googling showed that this is a specification with Http2 protocol.

We tried writing custom middleware to remove the header and add a header again. but still the response headers are in lower case

```
app.Use(
               next =>
               {
                   return async context =>
                   {
                       var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                       stopWatch.Start();
                       context.Response.OnStarting(
                           () =>
                           {
                               stopWatch.Stop();
                               context.Response.Headers.Add("X-ResponseTime-Ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
//returns in lower case
                               return Task.CompletedTask;
                           });

                       await next(context);
                   };
               });
```

How could we solve this, any hack to solve this ?

Comment: What is the problem in having in lower case if that is the specification

Comment: Most of the applications who have consumed this are checking the header with Capitals matching, we do not want to make changes at multiple apps who are consuming this